# Why this easy program isn't working?

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i = 100; 1 + 1);
    {
        std::cout << i << " = " << i *i << std::endl;
    }
    do 
    {
        std::cout << i << " = " << i *i << std::endl;
    } while (i = 100)
    getch();
}
```

Why isn't that working at all. It is sapoust to give cube numbers of numer from 1 to 100 and it just opens and nothing happens. can anyone help ?! I'm just a beginner and i cant solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of mistakes, e.g.

```
for ( i = 1 ; i = 100 ; 1+1 ) ;
```

should be:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i += 1 )
```

(note the removal of a stray `;` as well as the other changes).

Also:

```
while ( i = 100 )
```

should be:

```
while ( i <= 100 );
```

(note the addition of a missing `;` as well as the change from `=` to `<=`).

You probably also want to re-initialise `i` prior to the `do` loop, and increment it within the loop:

```
i = 1;
do 
{
    std::cout << i << " = " << i * i << std::endl;
    i += 1;
} while (i <= 100);
```

Comment: There are at least two errors in your "corrected" version.

Comment: Your for loop is still wrong

Comment: @T.C. it's a "work in progress". ;-)

Comment: The do-while-loop will run either for ever or never as long as `i` isn't changed within the loop.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: thanks, yes, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work the program opens and nothings happens

Comment: If you're still having problems then I suggest you post your latest fixed code in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Do-while-loops mus be terminated with a semicolon.

To increment your value must must write `i=i+1`, `i+=1`, `++i` or `i++` instead of `1+1`.

You have a semicilon at the end of your for-loop which makes the loop do nothing.

You are running you loops as long as `i = 100` which is always true. I also doubt that you meant `i == 100` as it would be always false. You better write `i < 100` or `i <= 100` (for both the for- and the while-loop)

You don't reset `i` between you loops.

And last but not least you don't increment your `i` in the while loop. so this loop will either run never or forever, as `i` never changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " = " << i *i << std::endl;
    }
    i = 1; //Reset
    do 
    {
        std::cout << i << " = " << i *i << std::endl;
        i++;
    } while (i <= 100);
    getch();
}
```

I hope I got it all.

Comment: `i=i+1` is also an alternative to increment `i`, but I think it is good to use `i++` or `++i` to increment.

Comment: @MikeCAT Added it to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`1+1` in your for-loop is the problem. You are caught in a infinity loop. You never increment `i` thus it never reaches 100 and never exits the for loop.
There is a second error as stated in other answers, too. Change in your for-loop `i = 100` to `1 <= 100`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
// delete because this is unneeded and emits error on some compilers
//#include <conio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i  ;
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) // fix second and third expression and remove junk semicolon
    {
        std :: cout <<  i  << " = " << i *i << std :: endl ;
    }
    i = 1; // add
    do {
        std :: cout <<  i  << " = " << i *i << std :: endl ;
    } while ( (++i) <= 100 ); // change = to <=, update i and add semicolon
    // delete because this is unneeded and emits error on some compilers
    //getch () ;
}
```

Comment: Thank but I still get an error "lvalue required as increment operand".

Comment: This code do work well on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aKwawz9CcAyucI8E).

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong, you probably want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i  ;
    for ( i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i++ )
    {
        std :: cout <<  i  << " = " << i *i << std :: endl ;
    }

    getch () ; //no clue what this is, but you probably know
}
```

Comment: The semicolon at the end of `for` line must be removed.

Comment: thanks, overlooked the semicolon..